# MS-Access_remove duplicates in table based on two dependant but unique fields

Tags: ms-access, dependencies, duplicates

I have a single table that has a PrimaryAuthor (surname) field and a PAInitials (null, first, or first and second initials) field. Together, (eventually) the two fields will return an author's 'last name','initials' from a new look up table for author's of literary references. Below is an example table of actual data.

I need to retain one of each data entry combination based on the two fields, while removing duplicate combinations. The problem I'm having is that there are valid duplicates in both fields individually:  i.e. more than one author with the last name of 'Carter' and more than one author with the initials of 'F.C.' but with a different surname. I want to retain only one unique record for the authors named Carter, G.J; Carter F.W; Calkins, F.C., and Armstrong, F.C.

I'm not SQL literate, and after trying my own ideas I tried to adopt code, but the frequent solutions for a 'duplicate entry delete on two fields' search involves deleting entries from two fields based on one field's duplicate entries (so only one Carter or one F.W. survives). Other potential solutions I found didn't work out because, I think maybe, of subtle differences in SQL syntax.

I'm using Access 2013 and the database is .mdb format. There are not enough records that processing time is a concern (other than by doing it by hand!)

[Sample Author Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE5Zq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an APPEND query to create a new table with the desired entries:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (PrimaryAuthor, PAInitials)    
SELECT DISTINCT PrimaryAuthor, PAInitials FROM Table
```

You can then set the new table primary key to multiple fields to restrict entries that create duplicates. Open the table > Design View > highlight both rows "PrimaryAuthor, PAInitials" > click Primary Key > Save.

Comment: The query worked perfectly after creating a NewTable by doing a structure-only copy of the Table. Couple of problems setting the fields to Primary Key:  Null as PK were rejected, and by setting PrimaryAuthor to PK I would lose duplicate author names (such as Carter).

Comment: Understandable since these two columns are being set to uniquely identifying each record. It would be my opinion (and likely industry best practice) to ensure the data is sufficient to include initials. Looking above at your sample table link you may consider incorporating the reference id, though I'm not sure what that's related to or how it's generated.